# Rspec controller "create" action succeed when format: :js but fails when format: :html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave

I got a `ProductsController` that I'm testing in a `type: :controller` spec. My tests pass when `format: :js` but fail when `format: :html`. Also in development environment I succeed to perform the same in html and in js.

The spec a simple POST to the create action with valid parameters, and assert that the record is created.

The particularity is that the `Product` model has_many `ProductImage`, and `ProductImage` uses CarrierWave to handle file upload.

Here is my spec

```
describe 'POST create' do
  [:html, :js].each do |format|
    context "as #{format}" do
      let(:valid_create_attributes) { {
          name: 'name', description: 'description', link: 'http://web.site/page',
          product_images_attributes: [{image: fixture_image('product.png')}]
      } }

      before { post :create, format: format, 
               product: valid_create_attributes }

      it { expect(Product.count).to eq(1) }
    end
  end
end
```

That test pass when `format: :js`, but when `format: :html` it fails. I've looked at the model validation error, and it shows `{:"product_images.image"=>[:blank]}`

So I check at the controller logs during the spec and I find a difference that I cannot explain

```
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: { "product"=>{"name"=>"name", "description"=>"description", "link"=>"http://web.site/page",
  "product_images_attributes"=>[{"image"=>"#<File:0x007ffe7ab41628>"}]}}

Processing by ProductsController#create as JS
  Parameters: { "product"=>{"name"=>"name", "description"=>"description", "link"=>"http://web.site/page",
  "product_images_attributes"=>[{"image"=>#<File:/workspace/my_project/spec/support/image_fixtures/product.png>}]}}
```

If you look closely at the `product_images_attributes` received param, you can see that in `:html` test the file object does not output the file path, when in `:js` the file seems to be correctly attached.

By adding `pp @product.product_images.first.image.file` in my controller it confirms that in the `:html` case, the file is nil

I tried:

- Configure database cleaner with truncation, and with transaction
- Run only `:js`, run only `:html`
- add `sleep 3` between the 2 tests (I don't even know why I did that)

Any idea would be greatly appreciated!

---

By the way, you may wonder about `fixture_image`. Here is the source:

```
def fixture_image(image)
  File.new fixture_image_path(image)
end

def fixture_image_path(image)
  File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'image_fixtures', image)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vikram's answer sent me to the right direction.

To upload file in rspec you cannot just send a `File` object like I did, you must use a `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` object.

```
def fixture_image(image, mime: 'image/png')
  Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new fixture_image_path(image), mime
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just true multipart in form:
Like

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :upload}, :multipart => true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'picture' %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you may have a point here, but how to integrate this in my isolated test?

Comment: Ok found it, thanks. You sent me in the right direction

Comment: Just a add only :multipart => true in form tag